# Iframe content not able to save in module params Joomla

Tags: joomla3.0

I am using Joomla3 with tinymce editor. I have created one module and adding one params in textarea
    
     
       
        
        
    I am adding iframe code
      
    in text area 
    but it's not saving. If i am save normal text string then it's saving
    Please help me

Comment: <iframe width="950px" height="600px" src="http://online.fliphtml5.com/zgsg/tvkw/#p=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen allowtransparency></iframe>

Comment: MyXML CODE
<field
     name="bookurl"
     type="text"
     label="MOD_FLIPBOOK_FIELD_URL"
     description="MOD_FLIPBOOK_FIELD_URL_DESC" />

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add a filter to your xml code.

such as:

```
filter="RAW" or, probably more appropriately, filter="HTML"
```

This will keep Joomla from cleaning your code.  There are a number of filters available to XML fields when creating modules.  You can examine the code here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/filter/input.php#L167 to see the exact list.

Answer (score 0):

What user group is the account you are using a member of?  Super Users and Administrator group types should have no filtering set by default but it sounds like you might need to edit those settings.

From the main menu:

System > Global Configuration > Text Filters (tab)

You will see all the available user groups for you website.  The group your user belongs to should have a Filter Type of No Filtering.  Another important note is its better to add the user account to a group with the permissions then to arbitrarily adding it to a group type typically reserved for registrants, guests or low-level editing.

[image]